# Definition of A Positive Statement Used Prior To A Negative Statement

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

What is the word for a positive statement used prior to a negative statement?  For example:  "She seems great but she's never on time."

Comment: Probably a *disclaimer* or maybe *hedge* or *softener*.

Comment: If there was another positive statement *after* the negative one, it would be a [***compliment sandwich***](http://99u.com/articles/37415/stop-serving-the-compliment-sandwich). I suppose maybe if there were just one negative statement followed by a positive one, that might be an ***open-topped** compliment sandwich*, but I doubt anyone would understand ***bottomless** compliment sandwich*.

Comment: Opposite of  *Backhanded compliment* i.e. *backhanded insult*?

Comment: A backhanded compliment is something that sounds bad, but actually means something good. A backhanded insult (maybe a veiled insult?) would be something that sounds good, but actually means something bad. Either way, they're one phrase, not two.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider ***sugarcoating***.
In your example, `she seems great` is the *sugarcoating* to make `she's never on time` seem like a milder or acceptable rebuke.

dictionary.com:

> **[sugarcoating](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sugarcoating)**
>   *noun*
>
> **3**.   a thing used to make something else considered unpleasant or disagreeable seem attractive or palatable.

Answer (score 0):

*Juxtaposition*

> noun
>
> 1. an act or instance of placing close together or side by side, especially for comparison or contrast.
> 2. the state of being close together or side by side.